# Extract numbers from a string by columns

Tags: regex, regex-group

```
1000  1000   500     0 
1     0     0     0
```

I have a list of numbers in a file and am looking to match them by column like below

```
1000 
1
```

```
1000 
0
```

```
500 
0
```

```
0 
0
```

Is there a way to achieve this via regex?

The closest I have come to matching it is with this pattern `[0-9]+.*\d`, but this doesn't match how I need to.

Comment: No, the use of a regular expression is not applicable here, but it's a simple thing to do in code. Suppose the two strings are `line1 = '1000  1000   500     0` and `line2 = '1     0     0     0'`. Then, in pseudocode, `arr1 = line1.split #=> ['1000', '1000', '500', '0']`, `arr2 = line2.split #=>  ['1', '0', '0', '0']`, `arr3 = [arr1, arr2].transpose #=> [["1000", "1"], ["1000", "0"], ["500", "0"], ["0", "0"]]`. Then do with `arr3` what you want.

Comment: @Michelle Ashwini, I guess desired regex can be constructed with PCRE if a table have strictly 2 rows. But I can't imagine regex if table have undefined number of rows. In any case desired regex will have poor performance.

Comment: While it's not too hard to do with lookbehinds/lookaheads and for any constant number of columns/rows, why would you ever do it? Just split the values by whitespace and access the correct array columns

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know how many columns you have in your data, and that you will match values from one column at a time, you can use this:

```
(\d+\b)(?=[ \t]*(?:\d+\b[ \t]*){3}$)
```

The number 3 needs to be changed to reflect which column you want. The last column needs 0, the one-but-last column needs 1, ...etc.